# Leaflet: my map is moving when popups open

Tags: leaflet

I have an issue and I can't find a solution by myself.

This is the map I'm working on.

When you check "Afficher les produits échangés", you can see a half-dozen popups opening simultaneously. And you can see my problem: my map is moving from Rome to China.

This is the code for my popups:

```
    var produits = new L.LayerGroup();          

var popupLocation34 = new L.LatLng(33.0, 39.0);
popupContent34 = "[popup content]",
popup34 = new L.Popup({closeButton: false, closeOnClick: false, offset:(0, 20)});

popup34.setLatLng(popupLocation34);
popup34.setContent(popupContent34);
L.circleMarker(popupLocation34, {
                    radius: 0,
                    fillColor: '#ffffff',
                    color: '#000000',
                    weight: 1.0,
                    opacity: 1.0,
                    fillOpacity: 1.0
                    }).addTo(produits);
popup34.addTo(produits);        

[...]


    var overlays = {
    "<B>Afficher les produits échangés</B>": produits
};
```

As you can see too, there are many popups open yet for sea, mountains and desert names, and apparently they don't make the map moving. In fact, I have exactly the same problem with them. I cheated, creating in middle Atlantic a popup with empty content, in order to center the map on Rome when it's loading, but it can't be a real solution.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I can only see one example point, but it could be a problem that you are inverting lat/lon.

Comment: Hard to tell without a full working example. Could you create a jsfiddle or similar?